# Does EXP carry over from RuneScape Combat Evolved Beta to normal Runescape?

Tags: runescape

I am earning lots of EXP on Runescape Combat Evolved Beta, but will this EXP carry over to normal Runescape?

Comment: Carries over to what?

Comment: To normal RUNESCAPE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the experience you earn in the Combat Beta will not transfer to the main game or affect it in any way. As [this page](http://services.runescape.com/m=news/evolution-of-combat-beta--live) on the Runescape site says:

> You should import your character save before playing the beta; once in the beta lobby, you will see a new Import Character button in the bottom-left of your screen. **Nothing you do on the beta worlds will affect your normal game save** – there’s no interaction with the normal game aside from importing your character from the normal game to the beta game. You cannot export anything from the beta game back to the normal game.

(bold mine)

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?